# Does it mean that a struct can't use other FnMut method after using a FnMut method?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

the minimal example is this([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/))

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    id:   usize,
    subs: Vec<Node>,
}
impl Node {
    fn refmut_nth_subnode(&mut self, n:usize)->Option<&mut Node> {
        if self.subs.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }
        else {
            return Some(&mut (self.subs[n]))
        }
    }
}

pub struct SearchStack<RefmutNodeType> {
    path:   Vec<RefmutNodeType>,
}
impl<RefmutNodeType> SearchStack<RefmutNodeType> {
    pub fn push(&mut self, node:RefmutNodeType) {
        self.path.push(node);
    }
    pub fn last(&mut self)->&mut RefmutNodeType {
        let end_index = self.path.len()-1; 
        &mut (self.path[end_index])
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut node = Node{id:0, subs:vec![Node{id:1, subs:Vec::new()}]};
    let mut lastnode = &mut node;
    let mut stack = SearchStack{path:Vec::new()};
    loop {
        stack.push(lastnode); // move
        match stack.last().refmut_nth_subnode(0) {
            Some(node) => {        
                lastnode = node;  // reinit
                continue;
            },
            None => {
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The compiler says that `stack` is mutably borrowed twice. I anticipate that the method `push` will drop the `&mut self` after it's over, and then I can pass the `&mut self` to `last` method. But the compiler prevent me from doing so. While the second error looks seems to be similar. What is the cause of this problem?

While the full error is here:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `stack` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:35:9
   |
35 |         stack.push(lastnode); // move
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^--------^
   |         |          |
   |         |          first borrow later used here
   |         second mutable borrow occurs here
36 |         match stack.last().refmut_nth_subnode(0) {
   |               ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `stack` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:36:15
   |
36 |         match stack.last().refmut_nth_subnode(0) {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `stack` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that `stack.push()` is holding a mutable borrow preventing `stack.last()` from being called, the problem is that the borrow by `stack.last()` is extended because of the assignment to `lastnode` and so `stack.push()` isn't allowed to borrow the `stack` mutably.

Lifetime elision allows you to omit the lifetimes on the `last()` method.  What you have here is equivalent to this:

```
pub fn last<'a>(&'a mut self)->&'a mut RefmutNodeType {
```

That is, the references have the same lifetime.  This means storing the reference returned by `last()` requires extending the lifetime of the mutable borrow on the stack.

```
lastnode = node;
```

This line is the culprit.  You can't hold a mutable reference to an element of a collection and modify the collection; this can cause a dangling reference if the collection is resized, for example.